# Создание и вывод массива дат

Tags: javascript, дата

```
  coffetime=new Array();      
  function myFunction() {

    var d = new Date(2018,1,15,11,33,30,0);
    for(p=0;p<15;p++){
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
    coffetime[p]=d;   
    //document.write("<br>"+d);// тут работает
  }    
  for(p=0;p<15;p++)  document.write("<br>"+coffetime[p]);
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
Fri Feb 16 2018 11:33:30 GMT+1000
Sat Feb 17 2018 11:33:30 GMT+1000
Sun Feb 18 2018 11:33:30 GMT+1000
```

результат:

```
Fri Mar 02 2018 11:33:30 GMT+1000
Fri Mar 02 2018 11:33:30 GMT+1000
Fri Mar 02 2018 11:33:30 GMT+1000
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d у вас одна, и каждый раз когда вы вызываете setDate, она меняется.
А в массиве у вас 15 [ссылок](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-reference) на одну и ту же дату. 
Вариантов это победить целая куча

```js
var coffetime = new Array();      

var d = new Date(2018,1,15,11,33,30,0);
for(var p=0; p<15; p++){
   d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
   coffetime[p] = d;   
}
// весь массив состоит из d
console.log(coffetime);

var d = new Date(2018,1,15,11,33,30,0);
for(var p=0; p<15; p++){
   d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
   coffetime[p] =d.toString();
}

// массив состоит из строк, полученных из d в процессе изменения даты.
console.log(coffetime);

// Разные d
for(var p=0; p<15; p++){
   var d = new Date(2018,1,15,11,33,30,0);
   d.setDate(d.getDate() + p);
   coffetime[p] =d.toString();
}

console.log(coffetime);


// Еще вариант с разными d
var d = new Date(2018,1,15,11,33,30,0);
for(var p=0; p<15; p++){
   d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
   // клонируем дату
   coffetime[p] = new Date(+d);
}

console.log(coffetime);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var coffetime = [];


 
  for (var p = 1; p <=15; p++) {
    var d = new Date(2018, 1, p, 11, 33, 30, 0);
    coffetime[p] = d;
    }
    
  for (var p = 0; p < 15; p++) 
  document.write("<br>" + coffetime[p]);
```

Comment: красиво, только у ТС дата начинается с сегодняшней, а не с 0

Answer (score 1):

**Ваша ошибка в том, что вы меняете и добавляете в массив один и тот же объект!**

Посмотрите на этот код, здесь каждый раз создается новый объект Date и кладется в массив coffetime.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var coffetime = new Array();
    var d = new Date(2018, 1, 15, 11, 33, 30, 0);
    for(var p = 0; p < 15; p++) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        coffetime[p] = new Date(d);   
        //document.write("<br>"+d);// тут работает
    }
    for(var p = 0; p < 15; p++) {
        document.write("<br>" + coffetime[p]);
    }
</script>
```